# Is it a memory leak if an Activity implements a callback and that reference is passed for a network call in another thread and the screen is rotated?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks, listener

**Scenario**

Let Activity **A** implements a listener say **OnCompleteListener**. This listener will be passed to another thread for a network call. Thus when the webservice is completed, we get a callback to the activity **A**.

**Question**

Suppose the web service call has started and in between, the screen is rotated, thus the activity's current instance will get destroyed. Since we passed the reference of **A** for the web service, will it get destroyed? Will the initial instance of **A** get leaked?

If memory gets leaked, then how can we clean up the unwanted instance? What are the best alternatives for callbacks that land on Activities?

Comment: Yes, that's a memory leak. Have the activity observe an in-memory or disk storage. Have the service write to that storage. Decouple the activity from the service. [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) may be able to help you do that.

Comment: It's will cause memory leak just like a well-known case when you did not unregister the `OnLocationUpdateListener`

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thank you very much. I have modified the last part of my question. Kindly, take a look. Please provide an answer with a little bit more elaboration. Thanks again

Comment: @HarikumarAlangode No, you cannot clear leaked memory! If it's possible, the GC should already have this feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question: **Yes, it will cause memory leak**.

Background tasks running independently of the activity life cycle can be a hassle. If we setup a network call listener, it will **hold a reference to your activity** to update data. Now if the device were to be rotated, a **new activity would be created** replacing the old one. Since a system service will most definitely outlive any activity, your "network manager - which will trigger update event for listeners" will **still hold a reference to the old activity**, making it impossible for the GC to reclaim the resources still tied to that "old" activity, resulting in memory being leaked.

If you want to check,  dump Java heap and use `Analyzer Tasks` and look at `Reference Tree` where the reference that is keeping the activity alive can be identified.

For your second question: **No, you cannot clean leaked memory/unwanted instance,..** even force GC to work using `System.gc()`. Simply because GC don't know if this instance is still in-use or not. If it see there is still a reference to your instance, it will mark this instance as reachable and do NOT sweep out.

If it's possible GC should already have its functionality and developers are not getting headache day by day caring about memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

It will be "destroyed" in android sense. `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` will be called but object itself will be leaked. So it is highly not recommended to do that. What you want is view listening to updates from data layer. When network call finishes it will push updates to listeners (Activity) if it exists, otherwise it will cache data. When activity comes back after rotation it can check cache for results.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added some more to the last part of my question. Please have a look. Thanks again

Comment: You cannot manually clear objects in Java because that job of GC. It will not clean objects when other objects have references to it, thats how leaks are born. Just what I mentioned, attach listener to data source, detach when activity rotates, attach again when it comes back. Cache during rotation or when Activity is inactivity. It can be done through many ways. Just to mention few, manual implementation, RxJava2, AC ViewModels.